# Как перенести строку в этой конструкции python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть конструкция, как переносить данные на следующую строку?

Вот в такой конструкции выдаёт ошибку:

```
unexpected character after line continuation character (<unknown>, line 33)
```

Вот код:

```
message=str(title)\n+str(text)\n+str(tags)\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно вот так:

```
message = str(title) + '\n' + str(text) + '\n' + str(tags) + '\n'
```

Но лучше воспользоваться интерполяцией строк (Python 3.6 и новее):

```
message = f'{title}\n{text}\n{tags}\n'
```

Или методом `format` (Python 3.*):

```
message = '{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(title, text, tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

`message=str(title)+'\n'+str(text)+'\n'+str(tags)+'\n'`